# cordova: Error: Android SDK not found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to run ionic code with Genymotion as emulator. I ma using windows 10. My C drive is run out of space and I installed everything in D drive.

However, when I run ionic run android, I get the `Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`

Firstly, I have the sdk directly at `D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\platform-tools` as the picture below:
[image]

The environment variables is set as below:[image]

When run adb at the path, it can run successfully[image]
I also set the SDk with both default and customs ANdroid SDk tools, but both return same error[image]

What else that I missed out that give the error?[image]

UPDATES:
as Djinggy suggest,environment variables set to a level up and path set for platform-tools and tools, however, **the same error still there** with `ionic run android`
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

open terminal in your ionic project:

```
In windows use these commands :

set ANDROID_HOME=C:\ installation location \android-sdk
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

In linux use these commands :

export ANDROID_HOME=/installation location/android-sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you have to set your `ANDROID_HOME` path to root sdk path (`D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\`) and adding to you `PATH` variable :

- `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools`
- `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform_tools`

Comment: How to add the path variable? can you to show in screenshot?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu so no, but simply edit your `PATH` variable adding this `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform_tools` at the end 
(add a semicolon before if there no one)

Comment: is it at the `D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\` , type `set ANDROID_HOME=D:\ dk-tools-windows-3859397\android-sdk` and then `set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools` ?

Comment: Just `set ANDROID_HOME=D:\ dk-tools-windows-3859397` (this folder should contains platform-tools and tolls folders. After do  `set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-too‌​ls`

Comment: same error still occurred. I input the command above in `D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397` directory, is it correct?

Comment: Try to pass by environment variable windows to edit user variable (for `PATH`) and system variable (for `ANDROID_HOME`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148231/discussion-between-behappy-and-djiggy).

Comment: I did change ANDROID_HOME in environment variable, and then set the PATH but not working. https://i.imgur.com/AhmgRNa.png

Answer (score 0):

The SDK root/home should be one level up from "platform-tools" not "platform-tools".[image]